# I need some help with either my SQL or my PHP I do not know which

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, activerecord, codeigniter

Hello I am creating a CMS and some of the functionality of it that the images that are within the content are managable.  I currently trying to display a table that shows the the content title and then the associated images, ideally I would like a layout similar to this,

**Content Title**
    Image 1
    Image 2
    Image 3
**Content Title 2**
    Image 1
    Image 2
**Content Title 3**
    Image 1

The SQL the returns the data is actually formed using Codeigniters Active Record class,

```
function getAllContentImages() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('contentImagesTable');
    $this->db->join('contentTable', 'contentTable.contentId = contentImagesTable.contentId');
    $this->db->join('categoryTable', 'categoryTable.categoryId = contentTable.categoryId');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The array that is returned is looks like this, I have cut the size down for readability.

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contentImageId] => 25
            [contentImageName] => green.png
            [contentImageType] => .png
            [contentImagePath] => /var/www/bangmarketing.bang/media/uploads/contentImages/2/green.png
            [isHeadlineImage] => 1
            [contentImageDateUploaded] => 1265222654
            [contentId] => 2
            [dashboardUserId] => 0
            [contentTitle] => sadsadsadassss
            [contentAbstract] => <p>Pllllleeeeeeeaaaaasssssseeeeee Work</p>
            [contentBody] => <p>Please work :-( please</p>
            [contentOnline] => 0
            [contentAllowComments] => 0
            [contentDateCreated] => 1265124038
            [categoryId] => 1
            [categoryTitle] => blogsss
            [categoryAbstract] => <p>asdsdsadasdsadfdsgdgdsgdsgssssssssssss</p>
            [categorySlug] => blog
            [categoryIsSpecial] => 0
            [categoryOnline] => 1
            [categoryDateCreated] => 1266588327
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contentImageId] => 28
            [contentImageName] => yellow.png
            [contentImageType] => .png
            [contentImagePath] => /var/www/bangmarketing.bang/media/uploads/contentImages/7/yellow.png
            [isHeadlineImage] => 1
            [contentImageDateUploaded] => 1265388055
            [contentId] => 7
            [dashboardUserId] => 0
            [contentTitle] => Another Blog
            [contentAbstract] => <p>This is another blog and it is shit becuase this does not work</p>
            [contentBody] => <p>ioasfihfududfhdufhuishdfiudshfiudhsfiuhdsiufhusdhfuids</p>

            [contentOnline] => 1
            [contentAllowComments] => 0
            [contentDateCreated] => 1265388034
            [categoryId] => 1
            [categoryTitle] => blogsss
            [categoryAbstract] => <p>asdsdsadasdsadfdsgdgdsgdsgssssssssssss</p>
            [categorySlug] => blog
            [categoryIsSpecial] => 0
            [categoryOnline] => 1
            [categoryDateCreated] => 1266588327
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [contentImageId] => 33
            [contentImageName] => portaski.jpg
            [contentImageType] => .jpg
            [contentImagePath] => /var/www/bangmarketing.bang/media/uploads/contentImages/11/portaski.jpg
            [isHeadlineImage] => 1
            [contentImageDateUploaded] => 1265714175
            [contentId] => 11
            [dashboardUserId] => 0
            [contentTitle] => Portaski - new product and brand launch by Bang
            [contentAbstract] => <p>Bang's experience in new product development has helped launch PortaSki &ndash; the pocket-sized device which is set to revolutionise skiing.</p>
            [contentBody] => <p>After developing Portaski's brand identity and positioning, Bang re-designed the product and its packaging ahead of launch in late 2008.</p>
<p>A media and PR strategy was devised and implemented using Bang's close relationship with two of the UK's most influential organisations in the Advertising and Media Buying industries. On-line advertising was supported with editorial reviews in the UK's leading broadsheets and tabloids, which combined with pin-point HTML direct mail to drive consumers to the new e-commerce site.</p>

<p>Impressive month-on-month growth has been achieved since launch, and the direct marketing activity resulted in an unprecedented 2.71% of targets going on-line to purchase a PortaSki.</p>
<p>For further information visit <a href="http://www.portaski.com" target="_blank">www.portaski.com</a></p>
            [contentOnline] => 1
            [contentAllowComments] => 0
            [contentDateCreated] => 1265718184
            [categoryId] => 1
            [categoryTitle] => blogsss
            [categoryAbstract] => <p>asdsdsadasdsadfdsgdgdsgdsgssssssssssss</p>
            [categorySlug] => blog
            [categoryIsSpecial] => 0
            [categoryOnline] => 1
            [categoryDateCreated] => 1266588327
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [contentImageId] => 26
            [contentImageName] => housingplus.jpg
            [contentImageType] => .jpg
            [contentImagePath] => /var/www/bangmarketing.bang/media/uploads/contentImages/5/housingplus.jpg
            [isHeadlineImage] => 1
            [contentImageDateUploaded] => 1265284989
            [contentId] => 5
            [dashboardUserId] => 0
            [contentTitle] => Bang launches Housing Plus
            [contentAbstract] => <p>Bang has launched Housing Plus, the new brand for the Central Borders Housing Group, along with new sub-brands Property Care and SSHA.</p>
            [contentBody] => <p>The Midlands based Group, with turnover in excess of &pound;21M, appointed Bang in 2008 following an open pitch of over 40 agencies. Bang's work began with an extensive marketing research strategy that challenged the Group's former positioning and brand structure.</p>

<p>The research unveiled that the housing sector demanded a values-led Group. This led Bang to develop the brave &lsquo;Together for the Right Reasons' positioning for Housing Plus.</p>
<p>Chris Garratt, Marketing Director at Bang explained "The housing sector has witnessed wholesale change in recent years. Much to tenant's dismay, many associations and Groups appear to be losing touch with their roots, we wanted to develop a Group for associations who place principles at the heart of their corporate strategy".</p>
<p>The repositioned sub-brands also play an important role in the Group's revised brand by highlighting Housing Plus' willingness to embrace and nurture individual identities. Chris Garratt continued "By adopting a &lsquo;house of brands' hierarchy from the outset, Housing Plus has sent out a strong message to prospective strategic partners".</p>
<p>Bang handled all aspects of work for the redevelopment of the three brands, including research, brand creation, naming, positioning, internal branding and communications, advertising, the brand launches, building the brands' on-line presence and the creation of a powerful brand film &ndash; which is already attracting significant interest from across the sector.</p>
            [contentOnline] => 1
            [contentAllowComments] => 0
            [contentDateCreated] => 1265285940
            [categoryId] => 8
            [categoryTitle] => News
            [categoryAbstract] => <p>The world at Bang Marketing moves fast, keep up to date w
            [categorySlug] => news
            [categoryIsSpecial] => 0
            [categoryOnline] => 1
            [categoryDateCreated] => 1265283717
        )
```

I need a way that I can get all the content images associated with the same content title in one group and then display under the content title.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You never need to use $this->db->select('*');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But long winded but you could do something like...

```
$titles = array();
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    $title = $row['categoryTitle'];
    if (!in_array($title, $titles)) {
        $titles[]['title'] = $title;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($titles); $i++) {
    $title = $titles[$i]['title'];
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('contentImagesTable');
    $this->db->join('contentTable', 'contentTable.contentId = contentImagesTable.contentId');
    $this->db->join('categoryTable', 'categoryTable.categoryId = contentTable.categoryId');
    $this->db->where('categoryTitle', $title);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
        $titles[$i]['images'][] = $row['contentImagePath'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns all the images and a content title in an array, I was hoping I would be able to get in an array the content title and the images asccoticated to that content title? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This question is kind of similar, isn't it: [Can I do this with just SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495473/can-i-do-this-with-just-sql)

I'm having to do this sort of thing as well in my project and my plan was to join the tables and then manually build the array from the returned rows. I would then pass that array back to the controller and then to the view.

I'm not sure this is the best way to go about it, but everything I've read indicates that it is.

This was another post I ran into when I was researching - [SQL: Selecting parents and their children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186227/sql-selecting-parents-and-their-children)