# Can I do this with just SQL?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter

At the moment I have two tables, `products` and `options`.

Products contains

1. id
2. title
3. description

Options contains

1. id
2. product_id
3. sku
4. title

Sample data may be:

`Products`
id: 1
title: 'test'
description: 'my description'

`Options`
id: 1
product_id: 1
sku: 1001
title: 'red'

id: 2
product_id: 1
sku: 1002
title: 'blue'

I need to display each item, with each different option. At the moment, I select the rows in `products` and iterate through them, and for each one select the appropriate rows from `options`. I then create an array, similar to:

```
[product_title] = 'test';  
[description]   = 'my description';  
[options][]     = 1, 1001, 'red';  
[options][]     = 2, 1002, 'blue';
```

Is there a better way to do this with just sql (I'm using codeigniter, and would ideally like to use the Active Record class)?

Comment: So, do you prefer an answer in raw SQL or for the Codeigniter ORM?

Comment: Either is fine, raw SQL means I learn whats actually happening, CI to keep the code clean!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start with

```
SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN options ON product.id = options.product_id
```

and work from there.

The example only works for products with at least one option available (which is required by your design, otherwise you have no place for the SKU).  But if some products don't have any options at all, you want:

```
SELECT * FROM products LEFT JOIN options ON product.id = options.product_id
```

Finally, it's considered good practice to list the actual columns you want to get back instead of SELECT *.

Comment: Thanks. However, is there a way to retrieve it as some kind of 2d table, where I have the product, and a 'column' containing the table of options?

Comment: @Josh.  Not in standard SQL and not, to the best of my knowledge (which is *not* definitive) in MySQL.  Some DBMSes allow multiple and nested results sets but it's very non-standard.  Also, an ORM will probably support this assuming you correctly declare the relationship in the DM and the ORM — then you would access the option records through a collection property of the object representing a product record.

Comment: Ah, I'll have a look into that then. Thanks for the fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to join products and options. Try this query:

```
select *
from products, options
where products.id = options.product_id
```

Answer (score 1):

select * from Products a,option b where a.id = b.product_id;

or

you can use

select * from option  where product_id = (select id from Products  )